# Client server communication between android app and server

Tags: android, security, networking, web, network-programming

I am building an android application which communicates with web server for authentication, and getting data from server. I am using HTTPS/SSL for communication using self signed certificate on the server and allowed that certificate in the android app . In this way i am sure that I am talking to a correct server. But how to make sure that server is getting a request from the right client.

What if I spoof the http request from the browser to send to server ?

How can server know whether it is getting request from the android application , is there any way to restrict server from handling requests only from the mobile app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a complex problem.

You could have a private certificate and its corresponding public certificate signed by a CA recognized by your server (just add the CA public certificate in the corresponding key store).
The main complication of that solution are:
-Somebody can steal the certificate and use it in another device (if this problem is negligible for your application, then this solution is OK)
-Certificate distribution and expiration: you need a solution for bootstrap, certificate distribution, and actions before certificate expiration.

Other solutions could involve having a Device ID, there are some providers for this, and using One-Time Password.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rodolk . It was very helpful. Just continuing with my previous question. I am trying to connect to the web server i mention in main question through browser , I could connect with http  but when i try to connect with https, server is terminating the connection . My understanding is there is only self signed SSL certificate installed on the server , so server should send its certificate and browser should pop the window of untrusted certificate. There is no client authentication happening on server , so why should server terminate the connection. Please correct if i am wrong.

Comment: @Prabhuraj, I'm glad the answer was useful. If you could mark it, I'd appreciate it. Regarding the next problem of server closing the connection, that could be due to different problems. If you could run Wireshark in the server and pass me the sniffing file with the SSL handshake, I will be able to help you. Maybe the best is to handle it in a different question so that others can benefit from our work and don't have to follow the  comments thread.

Comment: Did you get the sniffing of the SSL handshake? With that we will be able to solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry Rodolk . The server is not under our control. I am communicating with the server team.

Comment: Hi Rodolk . I checked the server logs. It was just that I was trying to connect to wrong port for HTTPS . Now I corrected it and its working fine. Thanks a lot :)